# el valor de la variable local nombre no va ser usado

Tags: java

Problema es que al declarar una variable de tipo String, cuando le asigno un valor eclipse me dice que el valor de la variable local nombre no va ser usado y no entiendo ese error.
Os dejo mi código para ver si hay algún fallo:

```
public class ClasseString {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        String nombre = "Carlos";

    }

}
```

Comment: El error te indica lo que es, has creado un recurso y no lo estas usando. Puedes agregar otra linea con `System.out.println("Hola" + nombre );` para que veas como el error desaparece

Comment: @Capt.Teach Gracias

Comment: Eso no es un error es una advertencia, que te dice que declaras una variable que no usas... Y por lo tanto te recomienda que la borres que no es necesaria... En otras palabras te indica que tú programa hace lo mismo con o sin la variables.

Comment: @CristhianJavierUlloaCarmona Gracias!!

Comment: Eclipse te está advirtiendo de que no estás usando la variable, si no la vas a usar no la crees.

Answer (score 0):

El problema es que creaste una variable y no lo estas usando, no es un error es una advertencia, debería desaparecer cuando empieces a usar la variable, por ejemplo agregando:

```
 System.out.println("nombre: " + nombre);
```

Espero te sirva, Saludos!